# Restrict access to all folders but one to local ips using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

I just set up a web server and I'm having some trouble configuring my .htaccess to apply the restrictions I want.

Basically, I want everything on /var/www to be restricted to local ips but one folder, that should be publicly accessed. This is what I currently have in my .htaccess (located at /var/www/.htaccess) and it seems to be doing the opposite or something:

```
//Deny access to all directorys but 'pepephone'
<Directory /var/www>
   Order deny,allow
   deny from all
   allow from 192.168.0.
   <Directory /var/www/pepephone>
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
   <Directory>
<Directory>
```

What do I need to change to achive the result I want? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

First, as @nlu posted, you can't nest Directory tags. And second, the Directory tag is not allowed in `.htaccess` files, so I had to do it directly on the apache `.conf` files.

So this is what it ended up looking like (both files are in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` folder, included by `apache2.conf`. Note that this directives are each inside a `<VirtualHost>` tag:

### 000-default.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride Limit
      Order deny,allow
      deny from all
      allow from 192.168.0.
</Directory>
```

### pepephone.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/pepephone/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

From: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#directory

> ```
> <Directory\> directives cannot nest, and cannot appear in a <Limit> or
> <LimitExcept> section.
> ```

You should use:

```
//Deny access to all directorys but 'pepephone'
<Directory /var/www>
    Order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 192.168.0.
<Directory>
<Directory /var/www/pepephone>
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
<Directory>
```